# Storing a enum list in azure table storage

Tags: c#, enums, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to store a list of enum object in Azure table storage but when azure inserts it, the value of the list is null.

```
public enum ExtractedType
{
    Image,
    Video
}
public class Request : TableEntity
{
   private List<ExtractedType> _ExtractedTypes = new List<ExtractedType>();
    public List<ExtractedType> ExtractedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return _ExtractedTypes;
        }

        set
        {
            _ExtractedTypes = value;
        }
    }
}
```

When i do an insert and try to get the data back from the storage, the list is always    null. Can azure not deserialise list of enums?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple workaround (similar to what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27770666/67824)):

```
public string ExtractedTypesFlat { get; set; } //for use by the Azure client libs only
[IgnoreProperty] public List<ExtractedType> ExtractedTypes 
{
    get 
    { 
        return ExtractedTypesFlat
                     .Split(',')
                     .Select(s => (ExtractedType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExtractedType), s))
                     .ToList(); 
    }
    set { ExtractedTypesFlat =  String.Join(",", value); }
}
```

As I mentioned in the other thread, it would have been nice if a simple backing value could have been employed rather than an additional public property (without the hassle of overriding `ReadEntity` / `WriteEntity`). Again, I'll link to a [user voice ticket](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6916615-provide-forceserializeattribute-for-tableentity) I opened that would facilitate that, in case you'd like to support the idea and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a List object cannot be serialized when storing an entity using Windows Azure Storage Client Library. However you can customize the serialization behavior of your entities by overriding the [TableEntity.ReadEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.readentity.aspx) and [TableEntity.WriteEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.writeentity.aspx) methods. This would also allow you to call the base implementation to make use of the built-in serializer/deserializer and add in support for the List type.

Comment: Can you do the same in the python API? I converted my list to JSON string but not sure this is the best approach.